# Why doesn't my for loop exit?

Tags: c, for-loop

C program. I am trying to make a multiple choice quiz. I have used a for loop to run from question 1 to 2 to 3 etc. However after running the program it never exits the for loop even when I have specified only count <=3. Why? Can you see what I have done wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{    
    char s;
    char response[]={'a','b','c','d'};

    int ,x;
    int count,result;


    printf (" Listo para empezar?\n\n Please type 's' for si or 'n' for no.\n");
    scanf ("%c",&s);
          if (s='s'){
                printf ("Bueno. Ya Empezamos!\n");
                }   

    for (count=0;count<=3;count++){
        printf ("1.Que significa la palabra 'conocer'\n");
        printf ("1.\t to like 2.\t to know\t 3. to do\t 4. to eat\n");


        scanf ("%d",&x);
        if (x=response[1])
        {
        printf ("Equivocado!\n 'conocer'significa: to know\n");           

        }
       else {
       printf ("Correcto!\n");

       }

       printf ("1.Que significa la palabra 'ser'\n");
        printf ("1.\t to be 2.\t to return\t 3. to be (location)\t 4. to eat\n");
        scanf ("%d",&x);
        if (x=response[0])
        {
           printf ("Equivocado!\n 'ser'significa: to be\n");
        }
       else {
            printf ("Correcto!\n");

       }
       printf ("1.Que significa la palabra 'poder'\n");
        printf ("1.\tto be able to 2.\t to run\t 3. to play\t 4. to put\n");


        scanf ("%d",&x);
        if (x=response[0])
        {
        printf ("Equivocado!\n 'poder'significa: to be able to\n");           

        }
       else {
       printf ("Correcto!\n");


       }
       result=(4/count)*100;
       printf ("%d is your percentage out of %d attempts\n",result,count);

       } 

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (s='s')` looks suspicious. (You seem to use = for == a lot)

Comment: The code, as shown, will not compile.

Comment: `int ,x;` seriously?

Answer (score 1):

- Your declaration of `int x` is erroneous; there's a comma next to the identifier.
- In C, the comparison operator looks like `==`, **not** `=`. **This** is the **assignment** operator.
- Your percent calculation is wrong; `int / int` is `int` not `float` or `double` or `long double`, so this will always be `0`. Furthermore, a `float` is printed out with the `"%f"` format string.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (x=response[0])
```

should be

```
if (x==response[0])
```

similar changes should be made in all `if()`s

Note that you are comparing a character with an integer.Also

```
result=(4/count)*100;
```

There is a division by 0 operation.

> Integer division by zero results in undefined behavior

Comment: ok. helpful thanks.  I'm not sure how have the number of questions divided by the number of attempts. can you explain what formula you would use?